# Generate a 3d Object?

Tags: discussion

There are a variety of languages and frameworks that can be used to output a 3d object, including, but not limited to, [codecad](https://github.com/Irev-Dev/curated-code-cad). However, many 3d frameworks or game engines could also be used this way. I think there are a range of interesting challenges that could be created here, but I'm not sure whether this is allowed. Is it/Should it be? And would the standard rules work well for this?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I've voted to close this question as off-topic, as I do not believe it is relevant to meta. However, I would instead recommend you pop into [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte), the site's chat room, where you can ask about anything